# change the color of flash cs6 createjs exported lib object

Tags: html, createjs

i've testing some code in using createjs + box2dweb, i exported a vector ball in blue color drawn by flash cs 6, here is part of the code.

```
var birds = (function() {

    var spawn = function() {
        //circle = new lib.ball1();
        //var birdBMP = new createjs.Bitmap("images/bird.png");
        var birdBMP = new lib.ball1();
        birdBMP.x = Math.round(Math.random()*500);
        birdBMP.y = -30;
        birdBMP.regX = 60.75;   // important to set origin point to center of your bitmap
        birdBMP.regY = 60.75; 
        birdBMP.snapToPixel = true;
        birdBMP.mouseEnabled = false;
        stage.addChild(birdBMP);
        box2d.createBird(birdBMP);
    }

    return {
        spawn: spawn
    }
})();
```

here i want to do change the color of the blue ball, how can i do that?

*********updated****************

inclucde js

change code

```
birdBMP.cache(0, 0, 121.5, 121.5);
colorRan1 = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
colorRan2 = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
colorRan3 = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

birdBMP.filters = [
     new createjs.ColorFilter(0,0,0,1, colorRan1,colorRan2,colorRan3,0)
];

birdBMP.updateCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about the createjs Flash Extension, but I highly suspect, that from the Flash Export there is also no way to simply "change" a color - you have probably three options:

1) ColorMatrixFilter - this involves caching ect. and I wouldn't recommend this for your purpose.

2) Draw another ball in the desired color and change the Bitmap to that other (differently colored) ball.

3) Or if it is a simple shape you can use the exported `lib.ball1()` method and extend it with a color-parameter. - In that case you would also have to change the references bitmap/shape, if you want to change the color post-creation.